# Chrome's print preview panel closes immediately after loading

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a page from our website using chrome's (CTRL + P) print, and the problem is that the print preview panel/window immediately closes right after (1-2secs) it loads. I tried it on other websites and it works fine.

I'm not really sure if this is a code (css/js) issue. I have tried disabling the plugin (chrome://plugins/) Chrome PDF viewer as per other people said, clearing cache, re-installing chrome.

Anyone who experienced the same thing?

Comment: The CSS code hides the page content from printing, it doesn't affect the browser print preview. You can try print it with Ctrl + Shift + P. Do you experience this problem only when trying to print a PDF from your website or it's happening the same when you try to print the home page of your website (for example)? Can you provide the link of your website?

Comment: Yes, I can print the webpage by using CTRL + SHIFT + P. This happens either printing a PDF or printing any page.